# -SpringBoot 3 -Eureka registry server -(username & password registration problem)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

The spring-cloud-config-server cannot register with eureka

spring-boot :3.0.0
spring-cloud.version : 2022.0.0-RC2

**Eureka application.yml**

`

```
server:
  port: 8761

spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-server
  profiles:
    active: dev
  security:
    user:
      name: user
      password: password
 
eureka:
  instance:
    instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${random.uuid}
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVER:http://user:password@localhost:8761/eureka}
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 5
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: false

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

`

**config server application.yml**

`

```
server:
   port: 8888

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    env:
      post:
        enabled: true

        
logging:
  level:
    com.netflix.discovery: 'DEBUG'
    org.springframework.cloud: 'DEBUG'
    
spring:
   application:
      name: config-server
   profiles:
    active: dev
   devtools:
    livereload:
      port: 35730
   jmx:
    enabled: true
   cloud:
         config:
            fail-fast: true
            discovery.enabled: true
            server:
              git:
                cloneOnStart: true
                uri:  ${GIT_CONFIG_REPOSITORY}
                skipSslValidation: true
                default-label: master
eureka:
   registerWithEureka: true
   fetchRegistry: true
   client:
      serviceUrl:
         defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVER:http://username:password@localhost:8761/eureka}
   instance:
         instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${random.uuid}
```

`
**The console output**

`

`

```
2022-12-11T15:15:50.152+01:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m15612[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://username:password@localhost:8761/eureka/}, exception=AuthScheme is null stacktrace=java.lang.IllegalStateException: AuthScheme is null
    at org.apache.hc.core5.util.Asserts.notNull(Asserts.java:56)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.auth.HttpAuthenticator.updateAuthState(HttpAuthenticator.java:229)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.needAuthentication(ProtocolExec.java:277)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:208)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec.execute(HttpRequestRetryExec.java:96)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ContentCompressionExec.execute(ContentCompressionExec.java:133)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:115)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:170)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:75)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:54)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:92)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:101)
    at org.springframework.http.client.support.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor.intercept(BasicAuthenticationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:87)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:71)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:862)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:764)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:646)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:145)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:135)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:121)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:80)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1045)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:958)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:396)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:247)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:242)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:68)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:320)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:365)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:375)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:179)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:362)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getTargetObject(EurekaRegistration.java:128)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient(EurekaRegistration.java:116)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:281)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:482)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getEurekaClient(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:54)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:38)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:83)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:587)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
    at com.application.cloud.ConfigServerApplication.main(ConfigServerApplication.java:18)
```

2022-12-11T15:16:20.204+01:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m15612[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[tbeatExecutor-0][0;39m [36mc.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Request execution failed with message: AuthScheme is null
[2m2022-12-11T15:16:20.204+01:00[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m15612[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[tbeatExecutor-0][0;39m [36mcom.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m DiscoveryClient_CONFIG-SERVER/config-server:b3790bfa-41c5-42ca-8e27-b70b219c0ab9 - was unable to send heartbeat!

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-2.0.0-rc.4.jar:2.0.0-rc.4]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) ~[eureka-client-2.0.0-rc.4.jar:2.0.0-rc.4]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) ~[eureka-client-2.0.0-rc.4.jar:2.0.0-rc.4]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-2.0.0-rc.4.jar:2.0.0-rc.4]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) ~[eureka-client-2.0.0-rc.4.jar:2.0.0-rc.4]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:837) ~[eureka-client-2.0.0-rc.4.jar:2.0.0-rc.4]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1401) ~[eureka-client-2.0.0-rc.4.jar:2.0.0-rc.4]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

`

`

the same code work in spring boot 2.6

> 

http://username:password@localhost:8761/eureka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. Try to create a `SecurityFilterChain` Bean:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .formLogin();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

This worked for me.

Here, I intentionally kept `formLogin()` along with `httpBasic()` to authorize via login form when the management webpage is opened via a browser.

Comment: Tjank you for your response , i resolved the problem  with the same solution . Thank you again.

Comment: .and() is also deprecated. Can you please update this code?

Answer (score 0):

Following the same solution proposed by @Sergey Dzeboev
just updating code that became deprecated.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;


@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authConfig -> authConfig.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .httpBasic(httpBasic -> {})
            .logout(logout -> {
                logout.logoutUrl("/logout");
                logout.addLogoutHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                    authentication.setAuthenticated(false));
                }
            });
        return http.build();
    }

}
```